# I have a dataframe in R where each cell is a list. how do I make each observation its own cell?

Tags: r

I have a large matrix where each column is its own dataframe in the form of a list. Everything in the same column has the same length, but the lists in different columns are different lengths.

|  | df1 | df2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| string | c("a","a","a") | c("b", "b") |
| id | c(1,1,1) | c(2,2) |

How do I make it so every observation is its own cell? I want to be able to export a table that looks like this.

| string | id |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | 1 |
| "a" | 1 |
| "a" | 1 |
| "b" | 2 |
| "b" | 2 |

I've tried flipping the axis and `unnest()` and `unlist()` but neither of those were able to produce what I want.

Comment: not sure why the second table isn't showing up, it shows up correctly in the preview before I posted.

Comment: Do you have a list column or string column? and what would be the class of your original data.  Can you update your post with `dput(inputdata)`

Comment: `unnest` works with `data.frame/tibble` if you have a matrix, may need to convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`

Comment: @akrun Converting to data.frame worked, thank you!